# alt-tab alternative

Tags: windows, c++

Let's consider the following scenario: In my desktop machine i have two applications opened side by side, a browser and a text editor(half size of the display for each application).

How can I switch between those two applications, but without using alt-tab or win-tab or mouse clicks?

If is nothing default built on windows xp/vista or 7 how can I do that programmatically using c++? For example to press alt+l(or alt+1), to activate the left window and the alt+r(alt+2) to activate the right window.

thanks

Comment: Why the close votes? The words "C++" and "programmatically" definitely make this a programming question.

Comment: @Thomas As I read it, OP is asking for a built-in capability or an existing app, or short of that "how can I do it", which is far too vague for an SO programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Create an AutoHotKey script to grab those keyboard shortcuts and activate the program you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the handles to those windows, you can use [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can get a windows handle if you know the title with [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx). [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147659) explains how to get a window handle if you partially know the title (non-exact match), though I've never tried.

For your hot-keys, look at [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD` as the hook type. You'll make a [`KeyboardProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984%28VS.85%29.aspx), which Windows will call on key-presses. Here, you can capture your specific key-combinations and activate certain windows.

That said, Windows provides hot-keys for you, as outlined in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7, you can switch to any of the first ten items on the taskbar (whether running or not) by pressing Windows+(1..0).  You can drag taskbar items around to change the order.

Comment: This works a little different in Vista: Windows-1..9 opens the corresponding quick link from the bar next to your start menu

Comment: Yes, which doesn't answer the question.  That's why I said `On Windows 7`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this AutoHotKey script:

```
~LAlt & Tab::Send ^#{Tab}
```